# Golang Unit Testing Erorr when test function with query db

Tags: unit-testing, go

i start learning unit test on golang, i have do a simple test than it work, but try on real case, i found some errors, this is my test code:

1. test code

```
func TestGetAllCompetency(t *testing.T) {
    _, err := competencyService.GetAllCompetency()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("failed to get competency")
    }
}
```

2. GetAllCompetency Code

```
func GetAllCompetency() ([]models.Competency, error) {
    data := []models.Competency{}
    res := database.Conn.
        Table("competency").Order("name").
        Where("competency.is_delete = ?", false).
        Find(&data)
    err := res.Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[Error] competencyService.GetAllData : ", err)
        return []models.Competency{}, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

Comment: What is the error; also while running test is your DB connection initialized

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete code. Where do you define the `database`?

Comment: ahhh, thanks for hint, it need connection function for the db